# Is there any way to convert my IMessage .ichat files into text files

Tags: macos

I have tried everything and just for reference my school has blocked the use of IMessage so I have no way of just using that to look and open my messages

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you provide some details on "everything" you have tried?

Comment: I have tried everything from this post https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72987/how-can-i-convert-ichat-logs-to-text-files but alot of these solutions are from 2015 and im not sure how to get 'baskup' to work becuase on there website it only provides commandline script which i am not too wise on http://peterkaminski.me/baskup/